# One code to support multiple version of Odata service

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Sorry for 2nd question on the same topic . I try to frame the question in better way.

our multi tenant SCP based solution supports both on premise (number of versions) and cloud version of S4HANA  as we have mix of customers from both the worlds.   We have a scenario where new fields are added in the odata service  in latest S4HANA version which are required to be used to develop a new application feature based on this field which will be consumed only by customers who are on the latest version of S4HANA.
But we also need to support customers which are not on latest S4HANA version (on premise)

My understanding on how possibly we can handle this -
1. Generate VDM on the latest odata version (with maximum fields)
2. Check if value in VDM field exists then only use it . This should help to avoid any unexpected runtime error

Can you please let me know if this is correct understanding or we should follow any different approach

Regards,
Apoorv

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to how to approach this problem requires first and foremost a good understanding of all the API versions that you want to support.

Ideally, and this I think would be the metaphorical grand prize, is if the oldest version offers everything you need and every newer version of the same API has only compatible (i.e. non-breaking) changes compared to that older version. In this case it should suffice if you make sure that your client code is based on this API and you're good to go.

If this is not the case, it comes down to what the differences are. If there are radically different ways to use the (semantically) same API in e.g. SAP S/4HANA OnPremise 1809 vs SAP S/4HANA Cloud 2002, I'd try to reflect this fact in my system. Now there are probably again different ways to approach this. For example, you could think about representing this via different destinations. So you'd need to check which destinations are present in the subscriber's subaccount and then use them accordingly. Alternatively (and I'm not sure whether this is possible), you might be able to somehow determine the target system's version and edition via some API call. This would probably also give an angle with which to approach this problem.

As is probably evident from my answer, I'm not aware of any catch-all elegant solution to this problem. Maybe there are other people who've dealt with this before.